# debugging phonegap apps on pc for phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

i am creating phonegap apps via phonegap build..i am able to check for  "normal" events and variables in the web inspector tools. but the browser doesnt understand phonegap events

for example:

```
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

this code throws an error as there is no 'deviceready' event.

How can i check for native phonegap events and methods on PC.

Note: i am using phoneGap Build and not the CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run an PhoneGap App in your browser. Luckily you have few options.

1. Use an emulator such as **[Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)**. This way you can use `logcat` to log your debug messages. The down side is that some features (e.g. push notifications) won't work in an emulator without setting up helpers.
2. Use **[Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)** with Chrome. This is my personal favorite, since you can use Chrome Developer Tools (including console) just as if you would if you were running your page in a browser. The down side is that you will always have to build your app and update it to your device. You can do this with hydration of course.
3. Use **[Weinre](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/debugging_remote_debugging_tools.md.html#Remote%20Debugging%20Tools)**. I can't recommend it, because I feel it's unreliable, slow and does not log errors. But you may wan't to try it out. It's easy because you don't have to do any configuration.

Here's a list of some other debugging options you may consider: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap. Notice that Ripple works only when using PhoneGap 2.x (and should not use it). Hope this helps.